# F# Code is not sufficiently generic (using a static member constraint)

Tags: .net, f#, blazor, bolero

I'm trying to create a generic function that checks whether a record is in a valid format, given the record implements the static member valid. When trying to use this in an ElmishComponent within the Bolero (Blazor) framework, I'm getting the following error

> This code is not sufficiently generic. The type variable ^childModel when ^childModel : (static member valid : ^childModel -> bool) could not be generalized because it would escape its scope

With the following code

```
module Modal =
    type Message<'childModel, 'childMessage> = | Confirm of 'childModel | Cancel | ChildMessage of 'childMessage
    type Model<'T> = { Display : bool; Title : string; Child : 'T }
    let inline valid (x: ^t) =
        (^t: (static member valid: ^t -> bool) (x))

    type Component<'T, ^childModel, 'childMessage when 'T :> ElmishComponent< ^childModel, 'childMessage> and ^childModel : (static member valid: ^childModel -> bool)>() =
        inherit ElmishComponent<Model<'childModel>, Message<'childModel, 'childMessage>>()

        // Error is highlighted on this line
        override this.View model dispatch = 
            cond model.Display <| function
            | true ->
                div [ attr.style (if model.Display then "background: lightblue;" else "background: grey;") ] [
                    h3 [] [ text model.Title ]
                    ecomp<'T,_,_> model.Child (dispatch << ChildMessage)
                    p [] []
                    button [ 
                        // This is where I use the valid function
                        attr.disabled (if valid model.Child then null else "true")
                        on.click (fun _ -> dispatch <| Confirm model.Child)
                    ] [ text "Confirm" ]
                    button [ on.click (fun _ -> dispatch Cancel) ] [ text "Cancel" ]
                ]
            | false ->
                empty
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be missing something, but it seems to me that a simpler approach would be to use an interface that the child model implements - then you do not have to bother with static member constraints at all:

```
type IValidable =
  abstract IsValid : bool

type Component<'T, 'childModel, 'childMessage when 
      'T :> ElmishComponent< 'childModel, 'childMessage> and 
      'childModel :> IValidable>() =
    inherit ElmishComponent<Model<'childModel>, Message<'childModel, 'childMessage>>()
    override this.View model dispatch = 
        let test = model.Child.IsValid            
        ()
```

Comment: Correct, this is what I ended up going with. AFAIK though I can't implement the IValidable interface on an existing type (ex: a third party component), which I can do with static methods. Although I suppose I could always create a new type that inherits from the 3rd party component and implement the interface on that

Comment: As some additional context I was trying to emulate type classes like this article: https://withouttheloop.com/articles/2014-10-21-fsharp-adhoc-polymorphism/